# How to Load a txt file to your program?

Tags: java, load, document, filewriter

For an introductory computer course assignment, we need to program a **very** basic accounting software with four accounts; Bank, Cash, Income, and Expense. One of the last aspects we need to include is the ability to load (from a .txt document created earlier by the program) data on these four accounts so to (I'm assuming) manipulate them further. 
If it helps, here is the code I wrote to save the data to a file:

```
System.out.println("Save your data. What would you like the file to be called?");
    reader.nextLine();
    String name = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Creating file...");
    try {
      file = new FileWriter(name + ".txt");
      expenseAccount.saveAccount(file);
      incomeAccount.saveAccount(file);
      bankAccount.saveAccount(file);
      cashAccount.saveAccount(file); 
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In which it calls the "saveAccount(FileWriter) method" as seen below:

```
  public void saveAccount(FileWriter file) {
  System.out.println("Saving Bank Account");
  try {
    file.write("Bank Account: ");
    for (int j = 0; j< bankAccount.size(); j++) {
      file.write((j+1) + ".   " + bankAccount.get(j) + "\n");
    }
    file.write("\n");
  } 
  catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I don't know how I would load a file saved as .txt and be able to manipulate the data. How would the program know which data corresponds to which account?
Any help is hugely appreciated :)

Comment: add an Id to the account?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a delimited file.    For example if you need 4 accounts, you would write a file like this.

```
Account 1;100.00
Account 2;200.00
Account 3;400.00
Account 4;800.00
```

This is using ; as a 'delimiter'.    You would read/write each line and populate an Account object to represent each row.   You can use println and readline using File Readers/Writers.     You can use a StringTokenizer to parse the lines.

Comment: It looks like OP's accounts each contain a number of entries (the loop from 0 to bankAccount.size()), so maybe you'd have an account number, a transaction number, and an amount...